# Office 365 Admin centre shows an unused assigned license - but who has it?

Tags: office365, license

I see this on the dashboard of the O365 admin center for a client I manage:

[image]

It seems to imply that 3 users have been assigned a license but only 2 have taken it up and used it. How do I find who the non-using user is to unassign that license and reassign to someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow what is described by [Microsoft 365 Reports in the admin center - Microsoft Office activations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/microsoft-office-activations?view=o365-worldwide):

> 1. In the admin center, go to the Reports > Usage page.
> 2. From the Select a report drop-down, select Office 365 > Activations.

Then you will need to interpret the chart.

> You can get a view into your organization's Office activations by looking at the Activations and Users charts.

In your case, click on Users:

> The Users chart shows you the count of users that are enabled, and users that have activated the Office subscription on desktop or devices.

If the user has not installed an office apps yet, the columns about desktops and mobiles devices will be empty.

Note: I have noticed that there are times when the chart is wrong, as it shows users that have installed the apps.

Answer (score 1):

You may also check your Azure Admin Center All devices that was registered.
https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_Devices/DevicesMenuBlade/Devices/menuId/